# Django installation dependency errors after rolling back to Python 3.7.6

Tags: django

I'm working my way through the tutorials in William S. Vincent's Django for Beginners. Everything worked fine until Chapter 4 (the Message Board app), when like a nOOb I ran into [the known bug](https://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/e5m7zv/accessing_admin_is_crashing_the_server/) that causes Django's web server to crash when attempting to serve /admin/ using Python 3.7.* in pipenv. So, I upgraded Python to 3.8.2, and it still didn't work. So I foolishly deleted 3.8.2 and rolled back to 3.7.6, and now I can't install Django at all with pipenv due to a variety of pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure statements.

I've reinstalled Python 3.7.6 AND 3.8.2, pip3, pipenv and Django (through Anaconda as well as outside of it), but I'm still getting the same litany of errors that won't let Django be installed in my virtual environment. Using pipenv lock --pre --clear doesn't fix it.

The telling line is "ERROR: No matching distribution found for django-3-0"

Does anyone have any idea how to resolve this or what packages I need to uninstall/reinstall?
Thanks much! :)

Answer (score 0):

Manually delete the whole pipenv cache directory,

> ~/.cache/pipenv - (Linux)
>
> %LOCALAPPDATA%\pipenv\pipenv\Cache - (Windows)

Also delete the previous virtualenvs which were created within the .virtualenvs folder. (or the entire folder)

> Default location: C:\Users\{username}\.virtualenvs

Also delete Pipfile.lock file and then recreate your virtual environment:

*pipenv shell*

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I tried all those...and the suggested cache dump commands that the stacktrace produced, but it still generates the same error: https://twitter.com/jasonsalas/status/1233966903363698688

Answer (score 0):

Well, **good news**! On a hunch, and to rule-out any weirdness, I tried recreating a clean Django install [by using virtualenv](https://hostadvice.com/how-to/how-to-create-a-virtual-environment-for-your-django-projects-using-virtualenv/), since pipenv is giving me problems. It worked! I must have borked something with pipenv when I removed/re-added/re-removed Python 8.x. Thanks for your inspiration for this workaround, @Magicoder!

Comment: ...and in hindsight, this tweak to the pipfile may have worked, too (by default, it's ** django = "[*]" ** : https://github.com/wsvincent/djangoforbeginners/blob/master/ch4-message-board-app/Pipfile#L9